# Having trouble sending a message to ROS

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, ros

I am pretty new in ROS. I am just trying to publish a message to a node in a linux server with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ros.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::string;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    char *ros_master = "*.*.*.*";

    printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
    nh.initNode(ros_master);

    printf("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
    string sent = "Hello robot";
    ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("try", sent);
    nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);

    printf("All done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me these errors:

```
 Error  C2664 'ros::Publisher::Publisher(ros::Publisher &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::string' to 'ros::Msg *'  LeapMotion     c:\users\vive-vr-pc\documents\visual studio    2015\projects\leapmotion\leapmotion\leapmotion.cpp    22  
Error (active)  no instance of constructor "ros::Publisher::Publisher" matches the argument list    LeapMotion  c:\Users\Vive-VR-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LeapMotion\LeapMotion\LeapMotion.cpp  22
```

I am on Visual Studio and there aren't a lot of tutorial from windows to linux, so I am confused on what to do. Many thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Hello World](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World#Add_code_to_main_for_Hello_World) example. You cannot send types which are not defined as messages, i.e. std::string is not a ros message type. What you need is

`#include <std_msgs/String.h>`

Define and fill the string messages

```
std_msgs::String sent;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("try", &sent);
nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);

ros::Rate r(1); // once a second
sent.data = "Hello robot";
while (n.ok()){
  cmd_vel_pun.publish(sent);
  ros::spinOnce();
  r.sleep();
}
```

Check out this [blabbler](https://github.com/ros-windows/win_ros/blob/hydro-devel/tutorials/win_roscpp_tutorials/babbler/babbler.cpp) example and these [tutorials](https://github.com/ros-windows/win_ros/tree/hydro-devel/tutorials).